# Can't figure out why program doesn't give output

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've written a program which asks users about the number of grades he needs to calculate an average for. But I don't understand why it does not give me an output. Here's my code:

```
def input_data():
    number_of_smth = int(input())

    return number_of_smth

def answer_output(array, avg):
    print("The average of ", len(array), " grades is ", avg)
    print("High is: ", array[0], "; Low is: ", len(array)-1)

def array_init(n):
    array = []
    for element in range(0, n):
        array[element] = input_data()

    return array

def sorting(array):
    for j in range(len(array) - 1, 0, -1):
        for i in range(j):
            if array[i] > array[i + 1]:
               temp = array[i]
               array[i] = array[i + 1]
               array[i + 1] = temp

    return array

def average(array):
    sum_of_array_elements = 0
    for element in range(0, len(array), 1):
        sum_of_array_elements += array[element]

    return sum_of_array_elements / len(array)

def main():
    print("Please type the number of grades")
    grades_list = sorting(array_init(input_data()))
    answer_output(grades_list, average(grades_list))

main()
```

Comment: `array = []` and `array[element] = input_data()` isn't a valid approach

Comment: @Bazingaa thank you for help

Comment: suggest you to first indent the code properly, no one can help you like this

Comment: @ShubhamJain Edited.

Comment: Include the input, errors, actual output and expected output to explain "doesn't give output".

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in `array_init`.  The line `array[element] = input_data()` fails with an `IndexError`.  This happens because `array` is empty.  There is nothing at location `element` to assign.  You can use `array.append(input_data())` instead to create needed item in the list.  You can greatly increase the readability and maintainability by using python built in functions like this.

```
def answer_output(array, avg):
    print("The average of ", len(array), " grades is ", avg)
    print("High is: ", array[0], "; Low is: ", len(array)-1)

def main():
    print("Please type the number of grades")
    number_of_grades = int(input())
    # use list comprehension to read in the numbers
    grades_list = [int(input()) for i in range(number_of_grades)]
    # sort the list    
    grades_list.sort()
    # average is the sum over the count
    average_grade = sum(grades_list) / len(grades_list)
    # print out the results
    answer_output(grades_list, average_grade)
```